# Adding a new VLAN to an existing VMware cluster

Tags: vmware-esxi, virtual-machines, vmware-esx

I need to add an additional VLAN to an existing VWware 6.7 cluster.  There is an existing VDS available, however I am not sure what the proper process would be to accomplish that.

I understand the main steps is going to be adding a new distributed port group for the VLAN setting the new VLAN number.  There are currently some setup:

[vds port groups](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o1H94.png)

What about these networks though?

[networks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oRSQu.png)

Thanks in advance!